# Installation libv8 on php

Tags: installation

Try to install v8js extension by command:

```
sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.5
```

but at the end of installation I got:

```
checking for V8 files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the v8 distribution
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/configure --with-v8js' failed
```

Also at the middle of installation I got question:

```
Please provide the installation prefix of libv8 [autodetect] :
```

What I have to answer?

Comment: What distro do you use, and which version of php?

Comment: I use ubuntu 14.04 and php 5.5.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install libv8-dev package first.

```
sudo apt-get install libv8-dev
```

pecl installer should discover path but if not. provide /usr/lib when it asked.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, not enough reputation to vote. I'm absolutely sure libv8-dev was installed right before... but your solution works.